# How to pass email value to url

Tags: php, email

Hi I'm here again with the same question

```
 <?php 
  $email="xyz@gmail.com"; 
  $decode=urldecode($email); 
  ?>


<FORM METHOD="get" ACTION="action1.php">
Type your first name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="FirstName"> <br/>
Type your last name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="LastName"> <br/>
Type your email:<INPUT type="hidden" NAME="email" value="<?php $decode; ?>">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Click and See">
</FORM>
```

I got the url redirect: http://example.com/action1.php?FirstName=jon&LastName=Kuri&email=xyz%40abc.com

but I need it to be http://example.com/action1.php?FirstName=jon&LastName=Kuri&email=xyz@abc.com

cause email is used here for username. So saying this wrong.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Warning:
The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded. Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have unexpected and dangerous results.Check this:http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Answer (score 11):

It's not wrong... you're wrong.  Reserved characters in URLs must be encoded to be valid, or they are ambiguous and might be used for their reserved purposes in the URL.  `@` is a reserved character, and must be encoded as `%40`.

PHP decodes this for you.  It's transparent to you, and you don't even have to worry about it.

Here is a reference for you:  http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm#whatwhy

Comment: but i need it in url because this is a user name.otherwise it says wrong.

Comment: @user3097168 What is wrong?  Anything properly parsing the query string (which PHP does) requires a properly encoded query string.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you even decoding the `$email` in the first place. To pass a string into URL, it is very much advisable to encode them so the special characters don't mess with reserved characters like `@`. In PHP, encoding and decoding a URL is as simple as calling `urlencode()` and `urldecode()` respectively.
Since you want to pass the email to a URL, you should be encoding it instead of decoding. 
I've modified your code to:

```
<?php 
  $email="xyz@gmail.com"; 
  $encodedEmail=urlencode($email); 
  ?>


<FORM METHOD="get" ACTION="action1.php">
Type your first name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="FirstName"> <br/>
Type your last name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="LastName"> <br/>
Type your email:<INPUT type="hidden" NAME="email" value="<?php $encodedEmail; ?>">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Click and See">
</FORM>
```

Now, whenever you have to use the email address from the URL, simply do the following:

```
$decodedEmail = urldecode($_GET['email']); // It will return xyz@gmail.com as a string, decoded.
```

Hope it answers your question.